# WM_COMMAND unabled to fulfil request unless clicked outside of application window,

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Currently creating an application that just outputs Physics equations + some historical and mathematical context. I've ran into this problem where I'm using `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` to sort out a list of these terms and when I click said term on the screen, expecting a definition to appear, it doesn't output anything until I've clicked outside of the application window(Visual Studio, Debug Terminal, etc)

[Cursed gif](https://i.gyazo.com/790aaed125642e7ddc78d195272a6fa3.mp4)

And I want to make it clear that I DON'T want to use a button due to GUI aesthetics.

Mundane WINAPI application creation

```
int main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Application";
    WNDCLASS window = { 0 };
    MSG msg = { 0 };

    window.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    window.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    window.hInstance = hInstance;

    RegisterClass(&window);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, L"PhysicsBox", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 600, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    //aMessageBox = CreateWindowW(L"edit", L" ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 165, 150, 400, 300, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The Juicy Window Procedure

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        aListBox(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (SendMessage(hList, LB_GETSEL, FORCE, 0))
        {
            CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Simple Text", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER, 200, 100, 100, 100, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0); break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    }
}
```

The void function that creates the list

```
void aListBox(HWND hWnd)
{
    hList = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"ListBox", L" ", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 3, 4, 150, 300, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LISTBOX, 0, 0);
    SendMessageW(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, FORCE, (LPARAM)L"Force");
    SendMessageW(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, WORK, (LPARAM)L"Work");
    SendMessageW(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, POWER, (LPARAM)L"Power");
    SendMessageW(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, EFFICENCY, (LPARAM)L"Efficency");
    SendMessageW(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, POTENTIALENERGY, (LPARAM)L"Potential Energy");
    SendMessageW(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, HOOKESLAW, (LPARAM)L"Hooke's Law");

}
```

Note: the MSG('s) placed in the "aListBox(HWND hWnd)" SendMessageW parameters are numerically ordered(from 0). So FORCE = 0, WORK = 1, and so on. Also **hList is a global variable** if that helps :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listbox is created without the [`LBS_NOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-box-styles) style and will therefore not send [`LBN_SELCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lbn-selchange) notifications to the parent window. Changing the first line in `aListBox` to the following fixes this.

```
hList = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"ListBox", L" ", WS_CHILD | LBS_NOTIFY | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 3, 4, 150, 300, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LISTBOX, 0, 0);
```

Also, the `WindowProc` does not return a result on all code paths, and does not call `DefWindowProc` for all messages that it does not handle. The following corrects those issues.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        aListBox(hWnd);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (SendMessage(hList, LB_GETSEL, FORCE, 0))
        {
            HWND hText = CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Simple Text", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER, 200, 100, 100, 100, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            ShowWindow(hText, SW_SHOW);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Other problems remain with the code, for example the `WindowProc` does not check the `WM_COMMAND` notification code and will happily create new windows over and over, but the assumption was that this was minimal code only meant to showcase the particular issue in the question.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The behavior described by the OP when running *without* the `LBS_NOTIFY` style bit is mostly accidental, due to `WM_COMMAND` not checking the `WPARAM` notification code. What happens is that clicking outside the app window causes the listbox to send a `LBN_KILLFOCUS` notification (which is being sent regardless of `LBS_NOTIFY`). *That* notification is the one which triggers the `WM_COMMAND` code  in `WindowProc` that creates the static control when the `FORCE` item is selected.